# How can I preg_replace a tag in the title on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I am attempting to locate ANY of the post TAGS in the POST TITLE and `preg_replace` the match with the tag surrounded by a `span` to add css (bold) to it.  The end result should be the post title with any tags bolded.

```
        <h2 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php 
                    $titlename = the_title();
                    $tags = array(just_tags());
                    foreach($tags as $tag) {
                        $displaytitle = preg_replace("$tag", "<span class=\"larger\">$tag</span>", $titlename);
                    }
                    echo $displaytitle;
                ?>
            </a>
        </h2>
```

As you can see in the code, I modified a few functions to attempt to get just the tags, no `$before` and `$after`.

```
function get_just_the_tag_list() {
    return get_the_term_list('post_tag');
}

function just_tags() {
    echo get_just_the_tag_list();
}
```

Comment: Your `$tag` variable in the `preg_replace` should not be in quotation marks.

Comment: Right... I forgot to change that back to see if for some strange reason, that might make a difference, which it did not.

Comment: You're rewriting `$displaytitle` for each `$tag`, so if the last tag isn't matched, nothing will change. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `preg_replace` is looking for the text "$tag" in `$titlename`. Take it out of quotation marks, or wrap it in curly braces `"{$tag}"`!

`get_the_terms_list` returns an HTML formatted list of terms. You want to use `get_the_terms`, and that is automatically returned as an array, so `$tags` should be defined like so (assuming this is in the loop and `$post` is accurate:

`$tags = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'post-tags');`

```
<h2 class="entry-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php 
                $titlename = get_the_title();
                $tags = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'post_tag');
                foreach($tags as $tag) {
                    $titlename = str_replace($tag->name, '<span class="larger">'.$tag->name.'</span>', $titlename);
                }
                echo $titlename;
            ?>
        </a>
    </h2>
```

This means that your `$displaytitle` is being completely rewritten for each `$tag`, and if the last `$tag` isn't found in the post title, nothing will change.

Comment: I have removed the quotes as mentioned in the comment below the question.  Still not getting any spans around the tags in the post titles.

Comment: When I view the source code, I ended up with the empty span tag at the end of the title... no tag in it (plus it shouldn't be at the end.

Comment: I've re-edited my answer to properly use the `$titlename` variable as declared outside the `foreach`.

Comment: I am trying this now... looks like a ; was missing too

Comment: @crowjonah it was me editing because you misused the `preg_replace` function. See my answer. There is another problem in his code.

Comment: It still does not add the span around the tag in the title... is there something wrong with the functions to get the tags?

Comment: There are _plenty_ of problems. Looks like `get_the_term_list` returns an HTML formatted list, and not something that you can just stash in an array.

Comment: okay... I figured.  I wasn't sure if there was a function which returns just an array or something easier to work with...

Comment: `get_the_terms` should work. Try my updated answer, and ditch your helper tag functions.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that since `get_the_terms` returns an array of objects, you will need to use `$tag->name`, and I previously forgot to apply the new definition of `$tags` into the main code block in my answer. If it doesn't work even after all that, you'll have to start `var_dump`ing `$post`, `$tags`, etc.

Comment: I am narrowing down the issue... I commented out everything on your example except $tags and then I echoed it and the page stopped displaying before the first tile on the page.

Comment: `post-tags` should be `post_tag`.

Comment: You also need get_the_title() instead of the_title() into $titlename as the latter is a direct output function.

Comment: Thank you... I feel like I am getting closer but the span tag is still not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Souldn't you just do something like this?

```
$titlename = the_title();
$tags = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'post_tag');
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $displaytitle = str_replace($tag->name, "<span class=\"larger\">$tag</span>", $titlename);
}
```

You don't need to use regular expressions because you want to replace the whole tag. The `just_tags` function is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into Wordpress filters. There is a filter directly on the_title(), which would allow you to perform this functionality.

```
apply_filters('the_title','my_filter')

function my_filter($title)
{
//do what you want and
return $title; //when finished altering.
}
```

If you want to stay the way you are you need

```
get_the_title()
$titlename = get_the_title();//inside the loop
or
global $post;
$titlename = get_the_title($post->ID);//outside the loop
```

plus crowjonah's answer, removing the quotes around $tag, although you probably need to make it `preg_replace("/" . $tag->name . "/", '<span class="larger">'.$tag->name.'</span>', $titlename  );`

Or Benjamin Paap's `str_replace`

```
str_replace($tag->name, '<span class="larger">'.$tag->name.'</span>', $titlename  );
```

Comment: right, before the str_replace, i was getting the span between every letter in the title